# PyInstaller runs fine but exe file with error: No module named

Tags: pyinstaller

I was packaging my app for Mac OS and ran into this issue. I tried to deal with this error by using some of the solutions that people suggest online, including: using --path & --hidden-import flags to specify the path of the missing module. However, neither of these worked.

The final PyInstaller command that I tried:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --paths="/path/to/dir" --hidden-import libs labelImg.py
```

This is the line of code where the error occurred:

```
from libs.combobox import ComboBox
```

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: When running the command, did you replace /path/to/dir?

Comment: @eten yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

Use auto-py-to-exe. This works unfailingly for me and avoids any issues while dealing with regular py2exe, such as not including the correct libraries. Rather than a command, this is a GUI interface which is easy to control and works every time. This can be installed with the command `pip install auto-py-to-exe`, and is simply ran with the command `auto-py-to-exe`. Once it opens the GUI, it should be self explanatory. You can use the Onefile option to make your exe either one file or a directory, and you can add files that your code needs such as fonts or images. If you want more information you can go to the PyPI project page.